# Finding the minimum value in an array (What's wrong with my code?)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

This is for my intro to C++ course. We are currently doing arrays and I'm trying to find the min value for each column of the array. here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

int main(){
int grade[4][30] = {{76, 70, 80, 90, 100, 83, 61, 63, 64, 65, 97, 69, 70, 79,60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 83, 61, 63, 99, 98, 66, 69, 70, 79},
                    {74, 70, 80, 90,60, 61, 93, 88, 73, 65, 91, 69, 70, 79, 60, 70, 80, 90, 60, 83, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 69, 67, 74},
                    {72, 70, 80, 90, 99, 84, 62, 63, 99, 65, 66, 69, 70, 79, 60, 70, 80, 90, 99, 83, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 69, 70, 77},
                    {69, 70, 80, 90, 60, 61, 86, 63, 97, 97, 66, 69, 70, 79, 97, 70, 80, 90, 88, 83, 88, 63, 64, 65, 66, 69, 70, 79}};

int a;
for(int x = 0; x < 4; ++x){
    a = grade[x][0];
    for(int y = 0; y < 30; ++y){
        if( a > grade[x][y])
            a = grade[x][y];
            cout << "a is " << a << " for the " << y << "time" << endl;}
    cout << a << endl;}



return 0;

}
```

My problem is I don't understand why in the last two loops the value turns to 0? The real answer should be 60 for each row.

P.S I used this to find the maximum and it worked, but don't get why it won't work here?

Comment: How about writing a function that finds the minimum of a 1D array and then using that function to solve your problem for 2D arrays? Programming is all about writing functions.

Comment: Is this your code to find the minimum value? if not, please include that instead, as this looks to find the maximum value.  I also agree with @NeilButterworth that a function to find result for a 1D would be useful

Comment: @Graeme: It's written misleadingly, but this actually does search for the minimum. It would probably be more apparent if he reversed the comparison to `if (grade[x][y] < a) a = grade[x][y];` though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ah yeah I see it now.  Doh! brain is half asleep it seems

Comment: @Graeme: If it's any comfort, I had an answer ready because a few minutes before, I'd started to write almost the same comment.

Answer (score 4):

> for(int y = 0; y < 30; ++y){

It is because for example your first array contains only 28 **explicitly initialized** elements and you iterate till 30 (see above). The elements which you didn't initialize yourself are initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your array initializers have less than 30 numbers.  Since your array is declared to take 30 elements, the remaining entries are set to `0`.

Since you don't appear to have 0s in your data, you could use `0` as a sentinel to know to stop the loop.